# Admob Rewarded Ads video limit

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

In my app I distribute coins to the users, every month user with highest coins will be rewarded by a gift from us. Here users can earn coins only by watching Ad mob rewarded videos. I want to know can i allow the users to continuously watch the rewarded videos unlimited times else do i need to add any restriction any limit to watch the rewarded video ad, also please suggest the best usage of using rewarded ads, how to avoid invalid activity and usage of other network rewarded ads along with Ad Mob.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit in reward ads,I think it is 20 video/day, depends on your application download it may increase

Comment: Where do you found that piece of information? Can you be more accurate and justify your comment please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about AdMob limits when it comes to showing rewarded videos to users. But other networks like Unity allow up to 50 videos per day as per my knowledge. You can look into other networks into like ironSource, PubScale, AppLovin, etc.